# Doxygen: Linking Typedef with Anonymous Enum

Tags: c, doxygen

I am searching for a good way to document the following enum / typedef design in a shared library that I have inherited.  There are many instances of the following pattern:

```
enum {
    VAL1,
    VAL2,
    VAL3
};
typedef u_int16_t val_t;

int16_t myfunc(val_t foo);
```

This obviously causes problems with Doxygen's link generation.

Unfortunately, I cannot change this to the proper `typedef enum { ... } val_t;` structure that one would expect as this library runs on many different embedded systems ranging from native 16bit to 64bit.  Per the C standard, an enum is guaranteed to be large enough to hold an int.  Thus, changing these into proper typedefs promotes their size from `sizeof(u_int16_t)` (2 bytes) to `sizeof(int)` (usually 4 bytes but not always).  Chaos ensues from storage size differences; nevermind the coordinated release nightmare required to rebuild all dependent software.

Given the above, **is there any good way to mark in the comment block preceding the enum that the below is actually an alias for the typedef?**

Failing that, I am looking for a solution that will concisely allow me to find these values from an arbitrary function signature.  I can name the enums to something arbitrary (ex. `val_enum_t`) so I have considered both `@see` mentions as well as direct links using the `#` prefix.  In both cases, another layer of links is generated.

My ideal solution would consist of the following:

- One click from function signature to enumerated value list.  Failing one click, as few clicks as possible.
- Inline documentation for the enums using `//!<`.
- If a direct association cannot be made, a single comment block to describe functionality which can be displayed on both the typedef as well as the enum itself.

Comment: did you ever find a solution?